# Partial function application prematurely runs codeblock when used with underscore

Tags: scala, currying, partialfunction, eta-expansion

Given:

```
def save(f: => Any)(run:Boolean) { if (run) { println("running f"); f } else println("not running f") }
```

I can call it with:

```
save("test")(true) -> running f
save("test")(false) -> not running f
save(throw new RuntimeException("boom!"))(false) -> not running f
save(throw new RuntimeException("boom!"))(true) -> running f and then exception thrown
```

Here's the curious behaviour with partial application:

```
save(throw new RuntimeException("boom!"))(_) -> (Boolean) => Unit = <function1> //as expected
save(throw new RuntimeException("boom!")) _ -> exception thrown
```

The codeblock is evaluated immediately without being passed in as a function. What is the difference between the above 2 statements?

Comment: You can find some explanations here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363013/in-scala-why-cant-i-partially-apply-a-function-without-explicitly-specifying-it

Answer (score 3):

**First case**,

```
save(throw new RuntimeException("boom!")) _
```

According to ["Scala Reference"](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) (§6.7), trailing underscore is used in place of the argument list, and expression is converted to

```
val f: (Boolean) => Unit = save(throw new RuntimeException("boom!"))
```

where the first argument of `def save` is immediately evaluated.

> The expression e _ is well-formed if e
>   is of method type or if e is a
>   call-by-name parameter. If e is a
>   method with parameters, e _ represents
>   e converted to a function type by eta
>   expansion (§6.26.5). If e is a
>   parameterless method or call-by-name
>   parameter of type =>T , e _ represents
>   the function of type () => T , which
>   evaluates e when it is applied to the
>   empty parameterlist ().

To make the things work as you expect, some modifications are required:

```
scala> def save(f:() => Any)(run:Boolean) { if (run) { println("running f"); f() } else println("not running f") }
save: (f: () => Any)(run: Boolean)Unit

scala> val f = save(() => throw new RuntimeException("boom!")) _
f: (Boolean) => Unit = <function1>

scala> f(true)
running f
java.lang.RuntimeException: boom!
        at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:6)
```

**Second case**,

```
save(throw new RuntimeException("boom!"))(_)
```

According to ["Scala Reference"](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) (§6.23), when placeholder is used as a replacement for an argument, the expression is converted to

```
val f: (Boolean) => Unit = save(throw new RuntimeException("boom!"))(_)
```

Comment: Really, according to the quoted specification I'd expect call by name to work. After all, in that case `e` is only evaluated when applied to the empty parameter list.

Comment: I agree with Daniel. If as the spec says the call gets converted to () => T then the function will not be evaluated until it is applied.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of call-by-name parameters under eta expansion is currently under review, see [this bug](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5610).  Your code works as you expect (that is, the line `save(throw new RuntimeException("boom!")) _` returns a function without throwing the exception) with recent nightly builds of 2.10. Let's see if it stays in until release!

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10761994/991432) for a related question on the general case of eta expansion not involving call-by-name.