# confusion in understanding of passing parameter in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

Two `groupBy` method in Spark's RDD are declared as:

```
def groupBy[K](f: T => K)(implicit kt: ClassTag[K]): RDD[(K, Iterable[T])]
def groupBy[K](f: T => K, numPartitions: Int)(implicit kt: ClassTag[K]): RDD[(K, Iterable[T])]
```

I define a function f as:

```
def f(x: Int): Int = x % 2
```

I could just pass `f` to the first `groupBy` as `rdd.groupBy(f)`.

Why I could not just pass `f` to the second `groupBy` as `rdd.groupBy(f, 10)` ? I have to use `rdd.groupBy(f(_), 10)` or `rdd.groupBy(x => f(x), 10)`.

Comment: The problem appears because there's a fundamental difference between methods (`def`) and functions in Scala. Take a look at this answer to see how they interact: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2394063/58808

Comment: try `rdd.groupBy(f _, 10)`

Comment: this q/a has useful info on the topic. Worth the read:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324247/eta-expansion-between-methods-and-functions-with-overloaded-methods-in-scala

Answer (score 3):

> I define a function f as:
>
> ```
> def f(x: Int): Int = x % 2
> ```

That's not a function, that's a *method*. The two are *fundamentally* different:

- Methods can be generic, functions can't.
- Methods can have optional parameters with default arguments, functions can't.
- Methods can have varargs, functions can't.
- Methods can have implicit arguments, functions can't.

These are 4 restrictions that functions have compared to methods. Now, if they are so restricted, why do we use them? Well, there is one major advantage functions have:

- Functions are objects, methods aren't (they belong to objects.)

This means: functions can be assigned to `val`s/`var`s, they can be passed as arguments to functions, methods and constructors, they can be returned from functions and methods. Methods cannot do any of that: Scala is an object-oriented language, all entities that can be manipulated by the program are objects … and methods aren't.

So, why does

> ```
> rdd.groupBy(f)
> ```

work?

Well, you can convert a method into a partially applied function (here "partially applied" means "partially applied to `this`", not to a subset of the arguments) via η-expansion:

```
val fn = f _
// => fn: Int => Int = <function1>
```

Here, as is so often the case in Scala, the underscore is used as a placeholder (in this case for the yet to be supplied arguments). We have fixed the `this` of the method and left the arguments open, and created a function corresponding to that method.

In *some* cases, Scala will know that you want to perform η-expansion even *without* explicitly providing the underscore. That's why

```
rdd.groupBy(f)
```

works. This is called *implicit η-expansion* (§6.26.2 case 3 of the Scala Language Specification) and, because of ambiguities, works only in a limited amount of cases.

However, after having explained all this, I must admit, that I don't see why your second example doesn't work. According to my reading of the spec, it should.

IOW: the *fundamental* problem you seem to be having is that you confuse functions and methods, but in *this particular case*, it should actually work (at least according to my interpretation of the spec, although clearly not according to the compiler writers' interpretation).