# Type inference in generic curried method in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, type-inference, currying

I`m experimenting with Scala and slightly confused by type inference problem.

Given the definition below, which compiles successfully:

```scala
case class SequentialHistory[+E](events: Seq[E])

trait Event

case class SampleEvent(value: String) extends Event

def addEvent[E, E2 >: E](event: E)(history:SequentialHistory[E2]):
 SequentialHistory[E2] = history.copy(events = event +: history.events)
```

I would like to understand why type inference not working properly and compilation of:

```scala
val hist = SequentialHistory(Seq.empty[Event])
//hist: SequentialHistory[Event] = SequentialHistory(List())

val histWithEvent = addEvent(SampleEvent("Does not compile"))(hist)
//error
```

result in compiler error:

```
Error:(21, 62) type mismatch;
               found   : SequentialHistory[Event]
               required: SequentialHistory[SampleEvent]
               addEvent(SampleEvent("Does not compile"))(hist)
                              ^
```

but, if I swap parameter lists in `addEvent` method definition:

```scala
def addEvent2[E, E2 >: E](history: SequentialHistory[E2])(event: E):
 SequentialHistory[E2] = history.copy(events = event +: history.events)
```

that would solve the problem, types inferred correctly and snippet below compiles:

```scala
val hist2 = SequentialHistory(Seq.empty[Event])
//hist2: SequentialHistory[Event] = SequentialHistory(List())

val histWithEvent2 = addEvent2(hist)(SampleEvent("Compiles"))
//histWithEvent1: SequentialHistory[Event] =
// SequentialHistory(List(SampleEvent1(Compiles)))
```

Why Scala compiler can`t infer types correctly in first version of `addEvent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't explain it with references to the compiler code or quotes from the Scala specification, but here's my reasoning.

When your function has multiple parameter lists, it's "curried", so it's a function from the first argument that returns another function, etc. So if you try to apply it just to one argument, all types will be inferred:

```
scala> val partial = addEvent(SampleEvent(""))(_)
partial: SequentialHistory[SampleEvent] => SequentialHistory[SampleEvent] = <function1>
```

Now you can't pass the second argument with a wider type. What happens here is [*eta expansion*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2394063/736957). But another way round it won't work:

```
scala> val partial = addEvent2(hist)(_)
<console>:14: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => addEvent2(hist)(x$1))
       val partial = addEvent2(hist)(_)
```

Here `E2` is fixed by the `hist` argument, but compiler can't infer `E`. But if you provide it both arguments, it sees that their types conform to the restrictions. I think in this sense the second definition is the same as defining it like `def addEvent2[E, E2 >: E](event: E, history: SequentialHistory[E2])`.

Comment: Technically multiple parameters lists and currying (classic, not how Scala doc defines it) are two different concepts. So you are saying potential eta-expansion affects type inference? It would be weird.

Comment: If all parameters are in one parameter list - type inference behaves differently (infers them in "parallel"), partial applying is available for multiple parameters in one parameter list as well, so it doesn't seem to be a reason